# Inverse of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, operator-theory

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and consider the space $X=V\times V\times V\times V.$

Consider the block matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ A_2^* & -A_1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A_1 = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb C$ and $A_2: V^2 \to V^2.$

We then consider $$K=(A-\lambda)^{-1}.$$

Question: Can we express the resolvent in the form

$$K = \begin{pmatrix} T_1(T_2-\lambda)^{-1} & * \\ * & T_3 (T_4-\lambda)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $T_1,..,T_4$ are some matrices and $*$ elements I do not really care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$The answer is no. Indeed, let
\begin{equation}
    A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 3 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right). 
\end{equation}
Suppose that the desired result holds for some matrices $T_1,\dots,T_4$.

Then, letting $L$ denote the upper-left $2\times2$ block of the matrix $K=(A-\la)^{-1}$, we will have $L=T_1(T_2-\la)^{-1}$. So,
$L(T_2-\la)=T_1$.
So, the upper-left entry, say $p(\la)$, of the $2\times2$ matrix $L(T_2-\la)$ cannot depend on $\la$, and hence $p'(\la)=0$ for all $\la$.

However, writing $T_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 u & v \\
 x & y \\
\end{array}
\right)$, we see that
$p'(\la)(74 - 20 \la^2 + \la^4)^2$ is a polynomial in $\la$ of degree $\le6$, with respective coefficients $u-1$ and $2(u-6)$ of $\la^6$ and $\la^5$, and these two coefficients cannot simultaneously vanish. So, it is not true that $p'(\la)=0$ for all $\la$, and thus
we do get a contradiction.

Comment: Would you mind I ask some simple questions which confuse me? If $p'(\lambda)=0$, should $p'(\lambda)(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$ not equal to $0$? Where does $(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$ come from?

Comment: @Hans :  $p'(\lambda)$ is a certain rational function of  $\lambda$ with denominator  $(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$, so that, as noted in the answer, $p'(\lambda)(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$.

Comment: I am confused. Your second paragraph says $L=T_1(T_2-\lambda)^{-1}$. $p(\lambda)$ being the upper-left entry of $T_1=L(T_2-\lambda)$ which is a constant matrix is a constant. How is it a rational function of $\lambda$? There must be a typo or something.

Comment: @Hans : $p(\lambda)$ must be constant **if** we assume that the desired result holds. As shown in the answer, this assumption leads to a contradiction, which implies that the assumption was false. So, yes, we do have a (useful) contradiction here.

Comment: Sorry, that really confuses me. How is $p(\lambda)$ defined? I thought it was defined as "the upper-left entry, say $p(\lambda)$, of the $2\times2$ matrix $L(T_2-\lambda)$". So the very definition of $p$ is premised on assuming the desired result holds. I must have missed something essential. To shed some light, could you please write out the details of where $p'(\lambda)(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$ comes from? Thank you, Iosif.

Comment: @Hans : $p(\lambda)$ is defined as the upper-left entry of the $2\times2$ matrix $L(T_2-\lambda)$, and this definition by itself does not assume that the desired result holds. However, the statement that $p(\lambda)$ does not actually depend on $\lambda$ follows from the equality $L(T_2-\lambda)=T_1$, which in turn follows from the assumption that the desired result holds.

Comment: I see. I computed entry $(1,1)$ of $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$. It is $\frac{11+6\lambda}{74-120\lambda}$. So $p(\lambda)=\frac{11+6\lambda}{74-120\lambda}(u-\lambda)$. $p'(\lambda)=\frac{-407 + 882 u - 444 x + 360 x^2}{2 (37 - 60 x)^2}$. So it seems $p'(\lambda)(74 - 20 \lambda^2 + \lambda^4)^2$ is not a polynomial of $\lambda$. I may well have missed something again.

Comment: @Hans : I think you computed the entry incorrectly. Here is the link to Mathematica calculations: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ0Dk9XZxuVFjkxkaEu9DYVn7yEowuTJC1V0

Comment: Sorry again for my mistake. I used Mathematica this time but am a novice user. I mistakenly set A-$\lambda$ instead of A-$\lambda$ IdentityMatrix[4], thinking they represented the same expression. 

I just want to suggest that maybe it would be clearer at least for me if you would put "Let $L$ denotes the upper-left $2\times2$ block of the matrix $K=(A-\la)^{-1}$." before the statement "Suppose that the desired result holds for some matrices $T_1,\dots,T_4$". But of course, it could just be me who is confused...  

By the way, I have up-voted your answer from the very beginning.

Comment: @Hans : I have edited the answer concerning the definition of $L$, to reflect your suggestion.